# Jquery find an element by the value of its name? (name=val)

Tags: jquery

I know how to find an object by `.classname` and by `elementname` and i think by `#idname` but how do i find by the value of its name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find elements by the the value of an attribute with

```
$('element[attribute="value"]')
```

where `element` is an arbitrary selector (`HTML element`, `.classname`, or `#ID`) and `attribute` can be any attribute that you put inside the tags, e.g. `src` for `img` elements or `href` for `a` elements or also `name` for form field elements.

For example

```
$('#ID')
```

could be rewritten as (assuming the element is a `div`):

```
$('div[id="ID"]')
```

Of course the later usage is no improvement but maybe it illustrates how the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) works.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('elementname[name=foo]')
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

You can search for an element by any of its attributes:

```
$('element[attr=val');
```

So, for a table with the name 'MyTable'

```
$('table[name=MyTable]');
```

Of course, that doesn't just extend to elements:

```
$('.MyClass[name=MyTable]');
```